# Related List: Show sub items from Master-Detail(Opportunity) in Account

Tags: salesforce, subitem

i hope you can help me with my problem... currently we have the following structure

```
+ Account XY
+--+ Opportunity 1
|  +--+ custom Object 1
|     + custom Object 2
+--+ Opportunity 2
|  +--+ custom Object 3
|     + custom Object 4
|     + custom Object 5
|     + custom Object 6
...
```

Account => Opportunity (Lookup)
Opportunity => custom Object (Master-Detail)

now i want to show all related custom Objects from related Opportunities in the relevanted Accounts
is there a way to solve this without adding a Lookup relationship from the "costom Object" to "Account"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need this lookup or you could do an inline Visualforce page with this list. The lookup option is actually not recommended since you would be placing an artificial reference on something just to have it display in the Account page. Better to create a VF page that has Apex which does a SOQL call to get the related Opportunity->Custom Object records.